# Compare counts of string occurrences

Tags: python, strings

Knowing my solution ...

> Return `True` if the given string contains an appearance of "`xyz`" where
>   the `xyz` is not directly preceeded by a period (`.`). So "`xxyz`" counts
>   but "`x.xyz`" does not.
>
> ```
> xyz_there('abcxyz') → True  
> xyz_there('abc.xyz') → False 
> xyz_there('xyz.abc') → True
>
> def xyz_there(str):
>     return str.count("xyz") > str.count(".xyz")
> ```

...evolved from this code:

```
def xyz_there(str):
    if str.count("xyz") > str.count(".xyz"):
        return True
    return False
```

I wonder if there's some rule that describes when you can flatten the IF and write is as a return value like I did?

Comment: Is this a question about Python semantics or are you asking for a review of your code?

Comment: @jacwah I can only get the answer from the review of that code hence the question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use boolean expressions directly.
When you return a boolean expression directly,
the code is naturally readable, and shorter too.
No need to write out a full `if-else` condition.

I don't think it's a "rule" though.
It's a general recommendation.

Your code has a bigger problem though: it's inefficient.
`count` will search through the entire string.
A better way is to use regular expressions:

```
import re

xyz_not_preceded_by_dot = re.compile(r'(?<!\.)xyz')


def xyz_there(str):
    """
    >>> xyz_there("abcxyz")
    True
    >>> xyz_there("abc.xyz")
    False
    >>> xyz_there("xyz.abc")
    True
    >>> xyz_there("abc")
    False
    """
    return xyz_not_preceded_by_dot.search(str) is not None
```

Comment: what's the best way to go about learning regular expressions, I see those are an advanced topic

Comment: Yes, regular expressions are extremely important in programming. I learned them a long time ago, mainly from the docs, for example the [re package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). That might not be easy reading, and probably more friendly tutorials exist today, but I don't know them.

Comment: I'm very grateful to you for pointing me to regex and everything else, if you ever decide to become a mentor, I volunteer as a disciple lol

Comment: is there any way to write that regex without using a negative lookbehind? :)